# Jest framework createElement import error

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-jest

I've done a bit of looking around and the general answer for this import error is make sure the `__test__` directory is added to the `.forceignore`. I have been following the [LWC Tests module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components) but I am still getting this error, I have a fresh SFDX Project with only what is described in the module, and the `__test__` directory is in the `.forceignore`

To be clear the tests run without issues, but the error is very annoying. Does anyone know what is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Note, I have tried the following:

- changing the import to `import {createElement} from 'lwc/'` this makes the directory wrong and invalid
- making sure that `**/__tests__/**` is in the `.forceignore`
- tried adding `**\__tests__\**` to the `.forceignore`
- removing the import line and readding it
- restarting all extensions

Comment: I have the same problem... You can change the import to '@lwc/engine-dom'; instead and it fixes the error, however, this import breaks some things when trying to use `createElement` on LWC where you overload the `render()` method it seems.